# How to output nothing

Tags: python

Hi I wrote a program which tells me if there is or not hexadecimals in the input.

```
hexadecimal = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F']
output = ''
for c in hexadecimal:
  digit = input('Digit: ')
  output += c.join(digit)
  if digit == '':
    print(output, 'is a valid hexadecimal string.')
    break
  elif digit not in hexadecimal:
    print(digit, 'is not a valid hexadecimal digit.')
    break
```

The complete code of this program works, the only problem is that I need to add this into my code when the user doesn't enter anything.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: What on earth is this supposed to be doing? `for c in hexadecimal`...`c.join(digit)`. This is very confused code.

Comment: Are you just trying to write a script that takes input and tells you if its valid hex or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another if statement before appending it to `output`:

```
if len(output) == 0 and len(digit) == 0:
    print("input is blank")
```

This checks that the user hasn't previously entered anything and hasn't currently entered anything, if both are true then tell them the input is blank.

Comment: where would I put this in my code because I am not appending

Comment: Before 'output +=' and after 'digit = input'

Comment: it says input is blank when nothing is entered but it also says is a valid hexidecimal string underneath it and I dont want it to say that

Comment: add `break` after `print()`

Comment: Put a continue statement

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `if`:

```
if digit == '':
  if len(output)==0:
    print('The input was blank')
    break
  else:
    print(output, 'is a valid hexadecimal string.')
    break
elif digit not in hexadecimal:
  print(digit, 'is not a valid hexadecimal digit.')
  break
```

Comment: Maybe you should try this code yourself it doesnt work at all

Comment: Of course I tried it before posting. Make sure your code is indented properly

Comment: try replacing that if statement you made with my code at the top it wont work

Comment: @cars maybe you should try to do your homework by yourself, instead of talking in that manner?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
hexadecimal = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F']
digit = input('Digit: ')

while digit is not '':
    if digit in hexadecimal:
        print(digit, 'is a valid hexadecimal string.')
    else:
        print(digit, 'is not a valid hexadecimal digit.')
    digit = input('Digit: ')

print('The input was blank')
```

It is better to use construction if digit in hexadecimal(it checks if provided input is in a given list) than doing for loop and inserting brakes.

Comment: its supposed too be a for loop

Comment: It keeps asking the user until they enter without writing anything

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Surround it with simple while condition.

Comment: can you edit your answer with the while loop. It is confusing in the comment

Comment: Did it now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this, could be to use the `string` module and the built in functions `all()` and `any()`.
`all()` returns `True` if all elements of the input are true (or if the input is empty).
`any()` returns `True` if any element of the input is a hexadecimal value.

`string.hexdigits` value is: `'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'`

**Code:**

```py
import string

digit = input('Digit: ')

if not digit:
    print('The input was blank.')

elif all(c in string.hexdigits for c in digit):
    print(digit, 'is a valid hexadecimal string.')

elif any(c in string.hexdigits for c in digit):
    print(digit, 'there are hexadecimals in digit')

else:
    print(digit, 'is not a hexadecimal string.')
```